# How to find whether a package is documentation?

Tags: apt, automation

As part of my work, I recursively find the dependencies of a package. While doing that, I like to skip the packages which are documentation. I can see most documentation packages have the suffix `.*-doc`. I can also see there is an entry `Section: doc` in the control file. Is there any other way to determine whether a package is a documentation? or does the entry `Section: doc` in the control file confirms this is a documentation package?

Comment: you've tagged `Debian" how does this relate to ask ubuntu?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu packages, but the control file belongs to debian format. I believe anyone who very well knows the control file or ubuntu packages can answer by question.

Comment: Unfortunately, the community here is a little bit obsessive about the site being Ubuntu only. I removed the Debian tag since you say you are using Ubuntu packages so the question _is_ about Ubuntu and the mention Debian is just confusing people (someone has already voted to close as off topic).

Comment: The `-doc` package name suffix certainly doesn't seem to be a reliable indicator, as you can confirm using `aptitude`, for example `aptitude search -F '%p' '?section(doc)' | grep -v -e -doc`

Comment: "Skipping the docs" never ends well, 55 years of making mistakes with computers says.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the feedback, Team. I will definitely look into it.